# ACL default::mask not being used for new file

Tags: permissions, acl, umask

I have a directory with the following ACL rules setup:

```
cd /nobackupp13/jrwrigh7
getfacl .
```

I get

```
# file: .
# owner: jrwrigh7
# group: a1983
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:a1983:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:a1983:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

However, when I create testfile in this directory, the `mask` does not take on the default value and restricts the permissions of the file to just `r--` instead of `r-x`:

```
cd /nobackupp13/jrwrigh7
touch testfile
getfacl testfile
```

I get

```
# file: testfile
# owner: jrwrigh7
# group: a1983
user::rw-
group::r-x                      #effective:r--
group:a1983:r-x                 #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::---
```

Supposedly `umask` should be overridden by ACL (see https://serverfault.com/q/349145/530204
), but here are the results of `umask` anyways:

```
cd /nobackupp13/jrwrigh7
umask
```

I get

```
077
```

Is there some other permissions system that is preventing this from working?

The end goal is to have every file created in this directory be `r-x` by the group `a1983`. The whole reason I'm going through this is that my research group have always run into issues accessing/running each other's files on compute machines we don't have admin control over. We are wanting to ensure that every script file is executable, regardless of whether the owner has set it as such.

Comment: What practical difficulties dose this cause? (update question to tell us) It is what I would expect (see my answer). However a directory should get `x`, as should an executable output by a compiler.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I've added the information to the question. tl;dr. I want all new files to have the execute privileges to the group

Comment: You just repeated your self. This dose not tell me why you want the files to be executable. What benefit is there in having regular files be executable?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I've updated the question to give more detail as to why we want regular files to be executable.

Comment: (Workaround) Note: execute is only a convenience with scripts. You can run them anyway, even if `noexec` is set on the file-system.

Comment: (Workaround) How about using a union file-system. This will add a layer on top of the file-system (or part of it). This will allow you to cheaply modify the files (or change mode), but for only your view of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### general information

When a file is created by the `open()` syscall there is a `mode` setting. Each permission the file gets must be requested in this `mode` parameter.

If the parent directory does not have default ACLs then the permissions of the file are `mode` combined with `umask`.

If the parent directory does have default ACL then these and `mode` determine the owner permission and the permission for others.

All other ACL entries are taken unchanged from the default ACLs. In order to achieve the same effect the ACL mask is not computed from the `ACL_USER`, `ACL_GROUP`, entries`ACL_GROUP` (as it is when ACL are set explicitly) but it is set to the group part of `mode`.

The mask value is determined by both default ACLs and `mode` and the default mask. It contains only those permissions which are contained in all three elements. So usually the default mask is reduced but it can be used to reduce the other values, too.

The results can be confusing if programs act "strangely". E.g. `gcc` creates the output file with mode `666` and later executes `chmod()` with `777`. But that only affects the permissions for the owner and others because the ACL entries have precedence.

### your case

- `touch` creates the file with mode `666`.
- The default ACL is set to `750`
- The result (permissions contained in both) is `640`.

Comment: So if `mask` is computed to be the most restrictive combination of the permissions given on file creation and the ACL rules, then what does `default:mask` do? Because it appears to do nothing from this explanations (and others I've found).

Comment: @JamesWright I made some more tests and added a paragraph about the (default) mask to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not a directory or an executable (output by a compiler), then it will not have execute permissions.

Remember umask is a mask. It does not add permissions, it only blocks them. The program that creates the file will use a mode of `rw`, the mask will allow this on the owning user, and block the `w` on the groups, and block all on other.

Comment: Right, but ACL does add permissions, right? And it is the mask that is currently blocking the `x` permissions for the file.

Comment: Does it? is it?

Comment: I believe ACL adds permissions, but I'm not sure, hence why it's a question. And yes, the mask is the what is blocking execute permissions for the file. If I run `setfacl -m m:rx testfile`, the "effective" permissions are no longer there and the group will have the prescribed `r-x` permissions.

Comment: At first I thought you are right. From the description in `man 5 acl` one would expect something different. I just did some tests. I will explain that in an answer.